# Run-time error '1004' Sorting

Tags: excel, sorting, runtime, vba

Hey guys i Keep getting a run time error 1004 Method 'Range' of object' _Global' Failed when i try to do this simple sort.

```
Sub Assy_Weld_TrumpfSort()
'
' Assy_Weld_TrumpfSort
'


Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim TableName As String
Dim theTable As ListObject

 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 TableName = sh.Name
 Set theTable = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(TableName).ListObjects(TableName)

  theTable.sort.SortFields.Clear

  theTable.sort.SortFields.Add _
  Key:=Range(TableName & "[PART NUMBER]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
  Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With theTable.sort
  .Header = xlYes
  .MatchCase = False
  .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
  .SortMethod = xlPinYin
  .Apply
 End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be getting that error because of

```
 Range(TableName & "[PART NUMBER]")
```

Try changing it to range like:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(TableName).Range("A1")
```

That will sort using column "A" as the first sort key.